# Select all rows of dataframe that have a minimum value for a group

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of dates, times, and values, and I would like to create a new dataframe with the date and value of the earliest time for each date (think like an opening stock price)

For example,

```
date    time   value
1/12    9:07      10
1/12    9:03      13
1/13   10:35       8
1/13   11:02      15
1/13   11:54       6
```

I would want:

```
date    value
1/12       13
1/13        8
```

Since those values correspond to the earliest time for each date.

So far I got:

```
timegroup = (result.groupby('date')['time'].min()).to_dict()
```

But can't figure out where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

```
df.sort_values(['date','time']).drop_duplicates(subset ='date')[['date','value']]
#   date  value
#1  1/12     13
#2  1/13      8
```

or

```
df.sort_values(['date','time']).groupby('date',as_index=False).first()[['date','value']]
#    date  value
# 0  1/12     13
# 1  1/13      8
```